# When include in Haskell TypeClass in a function when declaring its type

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, typeclass

I'm learning haskell with http://learnyouahaskell.com
I'm confused to know when I have to include the TypeClass into the function type declaration like this one:

```
reverse' :: (Int a) => [a] -> [a]
```

For example, in the recursion: http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion. There are examples when teacher includes the Typeclass and others only put the type without Typeclass.

```
repeat' :: a -> [a]
```

**When** I should include the Typeclass and In which cases is not necessary?

Comment: `Int a => ...` makes no sense. `Int` is a concrete type, not a type class.

Comment: You put a typeclass constraint when the function body uses a member of that typeclass.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time GHC can figure out what constraints are needed. Here are two ways to have GHC tell you what it thinks the most general type of a function is:

1. Do not put a type signature on the function, and at the ghci prompt use the command `:t functionName`
2. Use a type-hole `_` (GHC >= 7.8) as the type signature:

   ```
    repeat' :: _
    repeat' ... = ...
   ```

Both ghci and ghc will emit a message like:

```
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is typically best to design your functions with the minimal amount of restriction necessary. Does your `reverse'` function actually do anything that requires its contents to be of type `Int`? If not, then there is no reason to enforce the restriction that the contents are of type `Int`.